# Impossible to install PHP 8 on mac

Tags: php, macos

I have a problem when I try to install PHP 8 on macOS. I use the following commands :

```
brew tap shivammathur/php
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.0
brew link --overwrite --force php@8.0
```

But after, when I try to execute `php -v` I have this result :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuio.67.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
[1]    28817 abort      php -v
```

Can you help me ? It seems my $PATH var has a problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
brew install icu4c
```

or

```
brew reinstall icu4c
```

it solved for me